# Maven resources plugin dependency

Tags: java, maven, netbeans, nexus

I am trying to retrieve my project dependencies from a local network accessible maven nexus repository.

I have setup a repository entry in my settings.xml as well as an entry to the proxy.

To do this Netbeans says it needs to build the project before it can retrieve the dependencies. It runs a `mvn install` command and trys to download a maven-resources-plugin pom. By adding the proxy I have managed to get it to download the pom. But there are strict policies in place on the network in that it won't allow downloading of jars from the internet.

So a few questions

1. Why is maven trying to get this pom plus it's dependencies?
2. Is it possible to disable this?
3. If it isn't possible I can only assume I will have to: download the pom, alter it to point to my nexus repository and make sure the artefact id is added to Nexus. Is this correct?

Comment: It tries to download the maven-resources-plugin cause it's used as part of the life cycle and of course the dependencies of the maven-resources-plugin. If this does not work either your configuration (settings.xml) is not ok or the configuration of your project (pom.xml)...may be you need a different version instead the one which is offered through your internal Nexus..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Maven does not contain everything it needs to build your pom. You've used the maven-resources-plugin somewhere, even if it a transitive dependency of another plugin you're using. It needs to get it from somewhere. It will try your defined mirror first and then it will try the internet. (The maven-resources-plugin is used in the resources:resources goal as part of the process:resources phase, the first phase in most lifecycles. This means you are most likely also missing many more plugins and dependencies, your build just failed before it needed them.)
2. You can disable it by removing the relevant config from your POM, you will lose that functionality though.
3. You should just have to download which ever artifacts you need and then upload these to your nexus. The easiest way to download all dependencies you need is to use a machine connected to the internet and run `maven dependency:go-offline` on a folder just containing your pom

Comment: Thanks, the only thing in the pom which might be plugin related is a `<scm>` tag. Is SCM a plugin?

Comment: There are some plugins which are loaded by default. For example, if you're building a jar, maven will require this plugin.